# Numpy.linalg.eig function returning zero eigenvector?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a 45x45 matrix which Stack overflow isn't letting me include as it is too long. But if I throw this matrix into numpy.linalg.eig, it gives me an eigenvector of all zeros in the last column. What does that even mean?

Comment: Perhaps it means that the matrix is not diagonalizable, and hence not eigen-decomposable. Try with `np.linalg.eig([[0, 1], [0, 0]])`; the matrix here is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Yeah, many of my tests are pointing to it being a singular matrix. But I can't find a test which will reliably determine whether any arbitrary matrix (not necessarily square) is singular. For instance, this matrix also apparently has no nullspace when I try to use scipy.linalg.null_space. But it's causing massive errors elsewhere, as though it is singular.

Comment: No, eigenvalue being zero means there is a non-trivial null space. Eigenvector being zero means something different. And I suspect that the matrix is not even eigen-decomposable.

Comment: @j1-lee Right. That's what I realize. But what does a zero eigenvector mean?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I guess that it just means you don't have enough (linearly independent) eigenvectors (i.e., not eigen-decomposable). Eigenvectors are non-zero by definition. If the function returns zero vector, I guess it is just because "A * 0 = lambda * 0" trivially for any scalar lambda.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like the matrix is actually degenerate, which I suppose makes sense, actually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).